# Transform JSON to a compact format

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to Transform the following json

```
{ "application" : [
   { "name" : "app1",
     "policies" : [ 
                    { "name" : "pol_1",
                      "orderNumber" : "10"
                    },
                    { "name" : "pol_2",
                      "orderNumber" : "20"
                    }
                ]
   },
   { "name" : "app2",
     "policies" : [ 
                    { "name" : "pol_A",
                      "orderNumber" : "10"
                    },
                    { "name" : "pol_B",
                      "orderNumber" : "20"
                    }
                ]
   }
]
}
```

To the following

```
{ "pol_1":"10", "pol_2":"20" }
```

Using

```
jq -r ".application[] | select(.name==\"app1\") | .policies[] | {\".name\" : .orderNumber}"
```

I was able to get

```
{
 "pol_1":"10"
}
{ 
 "pol_2":"20" 
}
```

Any idea how I can merge them.  Am I missing something Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Use `map` to create a single array instead of two independent objects, then use `add` to merge its contents.

```
jq '.application[]
    | select(.name == "app1")
    | .policies
    | map({ (.name) : .orderNumber } )
    | add' file.json
```